# Using service in app.routing.module Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-dependency-injection

Is there a way to inject and use a service in the route list in the Angular routing module in order to dynamically change route data?

Like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: {title: myService.getTitle()}} // use it?
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
    constructor(private myService: SomeService) {} // inject it
}
```

How could I achieve dynamic behavior, like setting a custom title, in routes array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TitleResolver implements Resolve<Hero> {
  constructor(private service: TitleService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.service.getTitle();
  }
}
```

in router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
     path: 'about', 
     component: AboutComponent, 
     resolve: { // use `resolve`
       title: TitleResolver
     } 
];
```

Comment: Great! Could you maybe also tell me if I can access `route.data.someCustomProperty` and use it in resolve? Currently, it is not present when `resolve()` triggers. I've looked online, but no luck.

Comment: @dzenesiz hmm, seems that's not possible. How about storing that custom property in the service, then inject it into TitleResolver?

Comment: I actually managed to pass data like this `data: { myData: 'whatever}` and then use it in resolver by accessing `route.data.myData`. I have just one more question, if that's okay - do I need to set the resolved value manually in component, or will title get set automatically? I'm asking because it seems it won't be automatic.

Answer (score 0):

you can access `title` in your `routes`

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'about', customData: myValue, component: AboutComponent, data: {title: myService.getTitle()}} // use it?
];
```

in any components or services with:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  constructor(private router: Router) { };
  ...
  this.router.config[0].data.title;
  ...
}
```