# Angular's inject() returns new instance

Tags: angular, auth-guard, angular-injector

I have a basic auth guard defined like this:

```
export function authenticationGuard(): CanActivateFn {
  return () => {
    const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
    
    if (authService.hasAccess() ) {
      return true;
    }

    const router: Router = inject(Router);
    router.navigate(['/login']);

    return false;
  };
}

/* Another way, not working as well */

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authService.hasAccess() ) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    return false;
  }
}
```

And my `AuthService` is defined like so:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService extends BaseService {
  accessToken?: string;
  refreshToken?: string;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, 'auth');
  }

  hasAccess(): boolean {
    return !!this.refreshToken;
  }

  signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return super.post<AuthResult>('signin', { email, password }).pipe(tap(this.storeToken));
  }

  private storeToken(result: AuthResult) {
    this.accessToken = result.accessToken;
    this.refreshToken = result.refreshToken;
  }
}
```

The guard is currently only used in one route defined in `AppRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/account/account.routes').then(t => t.routes),
    canActivate: [authenticationGuard()]
   //canActivate: [AuthGuard] /* Not working as well */
   //canActivate: [() => inject(AuthGuard).canActivate()] /* Not working as well */
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And the `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppStoreModule,
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      serverLoggingUrl: '/api/logs',
      level: NgxLoggerLevel.TRACE,
      disableConsoleLogging: !isDevMode(),
      serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.OFF
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I make sure that it will load the global root'ed AuthService instance?

The problem isn't that it's not working, but that it's not returning the same AuthService instance that would be returned if I got the service via constructor reference.

Comment: for completeness can you show how you're providing AuthService in your application (bootstrapApplication / AppModule / on the router etc.)

Comment: It's provided in 'root', but I added anyway, btw Angular 16.2.3 :)

Comment: I managed to store the token in a secure cookie, but I would like to understand what's happening here. I have a sample project with Angular 16.2.3 as well with a working guard, the different is that it implements `CanActivate`.

Comment: You didn't post your routing module in entirety, but `inject` is only going to function properly called in the injection context.  https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context. The tool angular gives you is to use Resolvers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141018/using-service-in-app-routing-module-angular

Comment: There's no much right now... I see, but how would that explain about the old class way not working as well? The services are comming via DI